# Some iterations cannot collect data from the site

Tags: python, web-scraping

Recently I started getting acquainted with the web and in particular with web scrapers. For better understanding, I decided to implement a small program. I want to make a *scraper that collects all the links that users leave in the comments from the posts of the /r/Python Reddit thread.*

Here is the code I got:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.error import HTTPError


class Post:
    def __init__(self, thread, title, url, inner_links=None):
        if inner_links is None:
            inner_links = []
        self.thread = thread
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.inner_links = inner_links


def get_new_posts_reddit(thread: str):
    reddit_url = 'https://www.reddit.com'
    html = requests.get(reddit_url + '/r/' + thread).content.decode('utf8')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    posts = []
    try:
        for post_link in bs.find_all('a', class_='SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z _2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE'):
            posts.append(Post(thread, post_link.text, reddit_url + post_link['href']))
    except HTTPError:
        return []
    return posts


def get_inner_links(post: Post):
    html = requests.get(post.url).content.decode('utf8')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for link in bs.find_all('a', class_='_3t5uN8xUmg0TOwRCOGQEcU'):
        post.inner_links.append({'text': link.find_parent('div').text, 'link': link['href']})


python_posts = get_new_posts_reddit('Python')

for elem in python_posts:
    get_inner_links(elem)

with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as file:
    for elem in python_posts:
        file.write(str(elem.inner_links) + '\n')
```

**The main problem is** that sometimes this program works and sometimes it doesn't. That is, in 1 run out of 5, it will collect the first 7 posts from the thread and then find internal links, again, only in one of the 7 posts. I think the problem might be that I send requests to the site too often or something like that. Please help me figure this out

Comment: is 'Python' a string that you submit in a form? in case try to pass it as params={} keyword of request. What do you mean by 1 out of 5? = 4 exceptions? of what kind? have you tried to look at the server response? is it the same for all cases?

Comment: This is just part of the url here. Speaking of exceptions, I mean that the scraper finds links of a given type only on one page out of seven, although the reality is that they should be in 7 out of 7 cases.

The server response is the same everywhere - 200. But I tried to save the HTML pages that are received in the request and noticed this: it turned out that some of them came "empty", that is, no content was loaded onto them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that I was getting a page where the content hadn't loaded yet. I rewrote the parser on selenium and everything worked.